# Invoke function from a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting, type-conversion, typeerror

I have the following piece of code that sets/formats the price and gets the value that I am refactoring from an upgrade of our dependencies.

I need to pass the value from the form to the amountOnBlur function and I am not sure how to go as the blur function on dependencies only accepts types of e: (FocusEvent & {target: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement})

```
export const amountOnBlur =
  ({
     setAmount,
     currencyFormatting,
     paymentMethods,
     setPaymentMethod,
     setUserAmount,
     setError,
   }: {
    setAmount: Setter;
    currencyFormatting: CurrencyFormatting;
    paymentMethods: VendorPaymentMethod;
    setUserAmount: Setter;
    setPaymentMethod: Setter;
    setError: Setter;
  }) =>
    ({ value }: { value: string }): void => {
      const amount = formatValueAsCurrency(value, '', currencyFormatting);
      const { decimalPlaces, maxDp } = currencyFormatting;
      const userAmount = formatValueAsCurrency(value, '', {
        comma: false,
        decimalPlaces,
        maxDp,
      });

      setUserAmount(userAmount);
      setAmount(amount);

      const error = validAmountCurrency(value, currencyFormatting)
        ? ''
        : ERROR_POSITIVE_ONLY;

      setError(error);
      setDefaultPaymentMethod(paymentMethods, value, setPaymentMethod);
    };
```

I have refactored the function on the ui to this below but I cannot pass the value to the amountOnBlur function.

```
   // how to pass the value to amountOnBlur from onChangeReference?
  const onChangeReference = (e: (FocusEvent & {target: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement})) => {
        const value = e.target.value
        amountOnBlur({
            currencyFormatting,
            paymentMethods,
            setAmount,
            setError,
            setPaymentMethod,
            setUserAmount,
        })
    };
  return (
    <IField
      error={error}
      inline
      inputGroup
      join
      label="Amount"
      rangeUnderflow={ERROR_MIN_VALUE}
    >
      <IInput
        data-testid="amount-currency"
        name="amount"
        onBlur={onChangeReference} //cannot use amountOnBlur due to mismatch types.
        onFocus={displayUserValue(userAmount, setAmount)}
        required
        type={IInput.Type.Text}
        value={amount}
      >
        <span slot="append">{currency}</span>
      </IInput>
    </IField>
  );
```

Comment: `amountOnBlur` already expects six values, can't you just add this one as a seventh?  Or are you looking to pass this value to the function *returned by* `amountOnBlur`?  Which you don't appear to be invoking?  It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const onChangeReference = (e: FocusEvent & { target: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement }) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    amountOnBlur({
      setAmount,
      currencyFormatting,
      paymentMethods,
      setPaymentMethod,
      setUserAmount,
      setError,
    })({ value }); 
  };
  
  return (
    <IField
      error={error}
      inline
      inputGroup
      join
      label="Amount"
      rangeUnderflow={ERROR_MIN_VALUE}
    >
      <IInput
        data-testid="amount-currency"
        name="amount"
        onBlur={onChangeReference}
        onFocus={displayUserValue(userAmount, setAmount)}
        required
        type={IInput.Type.Text}
        value={amount}
      >
        <span slot="append">{currency}</span>
      </IInput>
    </IField>
  );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).